# hide and show animation jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I avoid the box animation of hide and show function? I want the hide to make the black div slowly disappear without the box animation.

```js
$("#hide").click(function(){
  $("#view").hide("slow")
});

$("#visible").click(function(){
  $("#view").show("slow")
});
```

```css
#view{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="visible">Visible</button>

<div id="view"></div>
```

Comment: `show` and `hide` are just shortcuts for jQuery's `animate`. Use that if you need more control

Comment: Alternatively use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` with a quick real hiding/showing afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` instead:

```js
$("#hide").click(function() {
  $("#view").fadeOut();
})

$("#visible").click(function() {
  $("#view").fadeIn();
})
```

```css
#view {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="visible">Visible</button>

<div id="view"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use animate with time frame.

```js
$("#hide").click(function() {
  $("#view").animate({
    "opacity": "hide"
  }, 1000);
})

$("#visible").click(function() {
  $("#view").animate({
    "opacity": "show"
  }, 1000);
})
```

```css
#view {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="visible">Visible</button>

<div id="view"></div>
```